# Git error pushing to github using gitextensions

Tags: git, git-extensions

I created a repository on github named Documentation.  I think created a local repository named Doc.

I added a remote named origin to the local Doc repository and pointed it to the proper github read-write URI.  Added and locally committed a file, but when I attempt to push to origin I receive the following error:

```
git push -u "origin" master:master
Done
ERROR: Permission to myUsername/Documentation.git denied to myUsername.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I can ssh to git@github.com and receive the notice that I logged in successfully.  I just can't seem to push to my repository.

I can clone the repository into a new folder, but if I attempt to add commit and push a new file I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find in [this GitHub support thread](http://support.github.com/discussions/issues-issues/552-gits-famous-error-permission-to-git-denied-to-user) all the checks you need to do with this error.

That would include:

- setup the `git user.name`
- setup the `git user.email`
- uploaded the contents of `/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to github's account page.
  without pasting any whitespace in it.
- add the proper remote origin without making typos : `git remote add origin git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git`
- to confirm that, check the `.git/config`.
  The directory is correct and not another directory:

```
    [remote "origin"]
            fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
            url = git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git
```

- check that `ssh git@github.com -v` gives a successful authentication, with the right username (any other username means that another GitHub account is actually used)

```
     Hi myuser! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

- check any denial from a proxy or firewall
- check that the key is offered, by looking at the output from -v:
- setup a `github username` and `github token`:

```
    $ git config --global github.user myuser
    $ git config --global github.token 0123456789yourf0123456789token
```

(Sets the GitHub token for all git instances on the system)
- create a `~/.ssh/config`

```
    [github]
        token = mytoken...
        user = myuser
```

Comment: I'd been using git bash and had ssh keys and for some reason this was causing an issue when git extensions was loading putty keys.  I still don't completely understand why it was causing issues, github said that I was properly authenticating, but removing msysgit and reinstalling it as part of gitextensions followed by verifying your steps resolved things.  Thanks